# Sending binary data via (C#)

Tags: c#, network-programming, tcpclient

Good morning,

I'm new to network programming but have been doing research and got the basics of setting up a server/client application. I would like to send binary data via TCP from the server to the client to parse and print out integers based on certain field lengths.

I'm basically creating a dummy server to send network data and would like for my client to parse it.

My idea is to create a byte array: byte[] data = {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1) to represent 8 bytes being set. For example, the client would read the first 2 bytes and print a 2 followed by the next 6 bytes and print a 9.

This is a simple example. The byte array I would like to send would be 864 bytes. I would parse the first 96,48,48 etc.

Would this be a good way of doing this? If not, how should I send 1s and 0s? I found many example sending strings but I would like to send binary data.

Thanks.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kj9VpauMV5A

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing bits and bytes.
A byte is composed of 8 bits, which can represent integer values from 0 to 255.
So, Instead of sending {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1}, splitting the byte array and parsing the bytes as bits to get 2 and 9, you could simply create your array as:

```
byte[] data={2,9};
```

To send other primitive data types(int,long,float,double...), you can convert them to a byte array.

```
int x=96;
byte[] data=BitConverter.GetBytes(x);
```

The byte array can then be written into stream as

```
stream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
```

On the client side, parse the byte arrays as:

```
int x=BitConverter.ToInt32(data,startIndex);
```

MSDN has great references on TCP clients and listeners.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you very much. I confused myself a bit. I have structures that I would like to send to myself and parse. They all vary in bit sizes.  One is 1280 and the other is 864 bits. The first 96 bits of the structures contain information about the type of structure it is (name, type, location, etc. ) How would I send myself a series of 1's and 0's ?

Comment: If its a structure, I would recommend sending it as a comma separated string, which would make it much easier to parse on the client side. If commas are a part of the data you're sending, you can use any other uncommon character as a delimiter (I mostly use |)